# saving H.264 encoded images with libavcodec

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I am getting H.264 images from an IP camera and want to save the encoded images (without decoding). I am using **output-example.c** from ffmpeg *(libavformat/output-example.c)* for this purpose. For Saving the raw H.264 image, I do the following:

```
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
if (c->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
        pkt.pts= av_rescale_q(c->coded_frame->pts, c->time_base, st->time_base);
if(c->coded_frame->key_frame)
        pkt.flags |= PKT_FLAG_KEY;
pkt.stream_index= st->index;
pkt.data= (uint8_t *)ulAddr;//video_outbuf;
pkt.size= out_size;
save_image(pkt.data, out_size);
```

Where *ulAddr* is the address pointer to the image and out_size is the image size. Instead of saving the images to a media video file, I want to save the individual images. save_image function simply uses basic *fopen* and *fwrite* functions for saving the images. If I decode the frame and then save, everything works fine. But I have problem saving the encoded frames. The encoded frames are saved with a very small size and then they cannot be decoded. 
Is there anything wrong? I will really appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: +1 for interesting question.  Strictly speaking, there is really no such thing as a "raw image" in H.264.  The closest thing you get is I-frames, the transform coefficients of which *can* be saved on their own.  Everything else (P-frames, B-frames) exists in relation to some I-frame.  Are you just after the I-frames?  If not, how do you intend to handle the other types of frames?  Finally, can you include more complete source, showing the part that works (the decoding and saving as an image) as well?

Comment: Well I think I created a little confusion with the word "raw image". I am getting H.264 encoded images and want to save the images without decoding.  All I have is the *uint8_t* address of the buffer and the buffer size. How do I save this image?

Comment: Yeah, you've created plenty of confusion.  Are you sure you're getting H.264 encoded *images* and not H.264 encoded *video*? There's a big difference.

Comment: I am getting H.264 video. I just want to save Intra frames because I think they can be decoded successfully. I am not interested in video, but in successive individual images.

Comment: I think I have begun to understand what you want to achieve.  However, you need to note that I-frames don't represent successive images (an I-frame occurs every 30 frames or so, the rest are P or B-frames).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tried that by detecting the I-frames. I-frames appear at an unpredicted rate and hence it is not a good approach. I now decided just to decode the frames and then save. The problem is that I am still not able to decode the frames correctly. I am using **output-example.c** as I told before. In the **write_video_frame** function, I try to decode every packet data, but it doesn't help. I am getting a **segmentation error**.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: in the original post, you said "If I decode the frame and then save, everything works fine."  Now you're saying "I am still not able to decode the frames correctly".  What exactly are you trying to do?  What have you tried?  What is not working?  Please try harder to describe your problem (you can edit the question).  Finally, if you upload your **full** source (like I mentioned in my first comment), people may be more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H.264 is not a "picture" encoding format, it is a "movie" encoding format. The encoder does not encode each picture individually, it looks at a group of pictures all together and spreads the encoding for any given picture among the pictures in the group.

If you look at a single encoded picture in most cases you'll find that it has references to other pictures that can be before are after it in the encoded stream. A decoder may need to be given several other pictures prior to being able to decode your target picture.

You may need to select a different encoding format that allows you to do what you want, with H.264 you can't. The formats that encode each picture independently of the rest are called "intra-coded".

Comment: Technically, you can still encode pictures using H.264 intra encoding.  See http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/h-264-for-image-compression/.  Why an IP camera would do this is beyond me, though.

Comment: Interesting. Intra-coded H.264 is also popular in the broadcast industry, the AVC-Intra format from Panasonic. But I'm not sure this makes sense on low bitrate cameras though, overall image quality will be noticeable lower if only I-frames are used.